# Python Selenium webdriver methods are getting failed with Timeout exception when a modal dialogue box is popped up

Tags: python-3.x, typescript, selenium-chromedriver, modal-dialog, timeout

1)I am using python and selenium to test an invalid login scenario  for a webpage authentication.
2)Once I am passing wrong credentials, a modal dialog appears on the screen.
3)After the dialog box pops up, any action I try to perform with the driver object , the command gets failed with Timeout exception.
4)I am unable to move the cursor nor click the ok button on the dialog box.
5)There  is no iframe or alert message. Its a dialogue box.
6)The underlying code for webpage is in typesscript and html as markup lang

Can someone please guide?

Comment: Hi! without any code is going to be hard to help. Please post the code you are running.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.